# Visiting nodes in a tree bottom up

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees, traversal

I have a problem that can be reduced to this one:

Suppose I have an unbalanced (almost random) tree. The leaves of the tree have one property already set, and all vertex (including the leaves) have another property that I have to update upon visiting.

To update that property, I need to cast a function `f[father_Vertex,{son_Vertex..}]` in an ordered way, as shown below:

Example

```
(*build some tree*)
s = KaryTree[23, 3, DirectedEdges -> True];
leaves = Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[s], 1];
(*Draw it*)
HighlightGraph[#, leaves, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20] &@s
(*Assign a property to the leaves*)
leaves = Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[s], 1]
s1 = Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, "leavesProp" -> RandomInteger[{1, 5}]] &, s, leaves];
(*Assign another property to all Vertex*)
s2 = Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, "toUpdateProp" -> ""] &, s1, VertexList[s1]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, to cast my function, I need to visit node sets updating the properties in a hierarchical order:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the easiest way to accomplish this navigation scheme?

**Edit**

The visiting order at each tree level is interchangeable {s1, s2, s3, s4} and {s5, s6, s7}

**Edit2**

Trying to be more clear. This is the desired  order of invocation. All calls to `f` within the same round could be done in any order. The red one could be done in the first or second round.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would guess you could simply go through them in reverse numerical order since they are numbered based on the layering.

Comment: Convert the graph to a linked list and use `Cases`?

Comment: @jVincent Nope, this is just an example

Comment: @R.M Not sure how to do it recursively in the hierarchical order

Comment: You can get the vertices ordered by distance from the root node. Pedestrian code for this: `In[180]:= distance[v_] := Length[FindShortestPath[s, 1, v]] - 1

In[196]:= orderedvertices = 
 With[{verts = VertexList[s]}, 
  verts[[Reverse[Ordering[Map[distance, verts]]]]]]

Out[196]= {23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}.` You can now fold your property setting over this ordered list of vertices.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I need (for example) the first `f` call to be `f[8,{23}]` or `f[5,{14,15,16}]`. Not sure how to get that with your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can build the list of elements of the form {parent,childrenlist}, ordered by tree depth (largest first), as below.

```
Clear[distance, ordervertices, orderedvertices, families, children, 
  orderedparents, orderedvisits];

distance[s_, v_] := Length[FindShortestPath[s, 1, v]] - 1

ordervertices[s_] := 
 With[{verts = VertexList[s]}, 
  verts[[Reverse[Ordering[Map[distance[s, #] &, verts]]]]]]

ordervertices = ordervertices[s2]

(* Out[245]= {23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, \
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)

families = 
 Map[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} &, 
  SplitBy[Sort[List @@@ EdgeList[s2]], First]]

(* Out[246]= {{1, {2, 3, 4}}, {2, {5, 6, 7}}, {3, {8, 9, 10}}, {4, {11, 
   12, 13}}, {5, {14, 15, 16}}, {6, {17, 18, 19}}, {7, {20, 21, 
   22}}, {8, {23}}} *)

Map[(children[#[[1]]] = #[[2]]) &, families];

orderedparents = 
 Select[ordervertices, MemberQ[families[[All, 1]], #] &]

(* Out[249]= {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)

orderedvisits = Map[{#, children[#]} &, orderedparents]

(* Out[250]= {{8, {23}}, {7, {20, 21, 22}}, {6, {17, 18, 19}}, {5, {14, 
   15, 16}}, {4, {11, 12, 13}}, {3, {8, 9, 10}}, {2, {5, 6, 
   7}}, {1, {2, 3, 4}}} *)
```

Probably does not answer your question, but way too long for a comment. I'm sure the code could be improved also, though it should be fine for smallish graphs.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you say `Probably does not answer your question`. I think it does! Is there some subtlety escaping me?

Comment: No subtlety, I just was not sure if the result gave quite what you needed for subsequent traversal and property additions. A part of my confusion stems from inexperience with Graph[] objects. had it been non-atomic, I think it would have been straightforward to traverse by Level. But as a Graph?...Let's just say I'm still in the Stone Age where those are concerned.

Comment: Ok, preventively upvoted :). I'll test it and report again. Thanks!

Comment: or you could get orders by BreadthFirstScan. It group the result by round: set = Rest[
  Reap[BreadthFirstScan[s, 
     1, {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[{#2, #1, #3}] &)}]][[2, 1]]];
Reverse[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[#, First] & /@ 
  GatherBy[set, Last][[All, All, {1, 2}]]]

Comment: @haimir Thanks. I had messed a bit with BreadthFirstScan but was not getting it to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If it is okay for the properties to be updated in a post-order depth-first traversal, you can use TreeFold:

```
In[49]:= g = KaryTree[23, 3];

In[51]:= t = GraphTree[g];

In[52]:= TreeFold[f, t]

Out[52]= f[1, {f[
   2, {f[5, {f[14, {}], f[15, {}], f[16, {}]}], 
    f[6, {f[17, {}], f[18, {}], f[19, {}]}], 
    f[7, {f[20, {}], f[21, {}], f[22, {}]}]}], 
  f[3, {f[8, {f[23, {}]}], f[9, {}], f[10, {}]}], 
  f[4, {f[11, {}], f[12, {}], f[13, {}]}]}]
```

`f[parent,{child1, child2, ...}]` is still evaluated after each of the `f[childi, ...]`, but vertices in other branches are not visited until after the current branch is completed; e.g. S4 comes after S5.